# Не могу разобраться с подключением библиотеки CS50 на gcc

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, clang, cs50

Всем привет. Потихоньку прохожу курс CS50. Сижу на Windows 10 через VSCode с WSL Ubuntu.
При компиляции программы с функцией get_int с помощью gcc выдает:

```
gcc -lcs50 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -lcs50 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o main main.o
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `get_int'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:13: main] Error 1
```

Библиотеку устанавливал командами:

```
$ curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/cs50/repo/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
$ sudo apt-get install libcs50
```

Вот Makefile

```
SRCS = main.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
CFLAGS = -lcs50 -Wall -Wextra -Werror
TARGET = main
CC = gcc

all: $(TARGET)

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

clean:
        rm -rf ./*.o

fclean:
        rm -rf $(TARGET) *.o

re: fclean all
```

Если компилировать через clang, ошибок нет, и программа запускается нормально.
Но с clang другая беда, при компиляции через makefile выдает:

```
clang -lcs50 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c main.c -o main.o
clang: error: -lcs50: 'linker' input unused [-Werror,-Wunused-command-line-argument]
make: *** [makefile:10: main.o] Error 1
```

Если убрать флаг -lcs50 или изменить компилятор на gcc в строке:

```
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

программа нормально компилируется и запускается.
Объясните пожалуйста, в чем проблема с gcc, и почему clang не компилирует объектные файлы с флагом -lcs50

Вот с таким makefile все работает:

```
SRCS = main.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
CFLAGS = -lcs50 -Wall -Wextra -Werror
TARGET = main
CC = clang

all: $(TARGET)

.c.o:
        $(CC) -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

clean:
        rm -rf ./*.o

fclean:
        rm -rf $(TARGET) *.o

re: fclean all
```

Еще вопрос, нужны ли вообще флаги при создании объектных файлов:

```
.c.o:
        $(CC) -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c $< -o $@
```

Учиться только начинаю, поэтому если проблема глупая, заранее прошу прощения.

Comment: C флагом `-c` флаг `-lcs50` не нужен. Там где у вас компоновка перенесите ` -lcs50` в конец строки. Он должен идти после упоминания всех `*.o` файлов.

Comment: Флаги нужны при создании объектных файлов - это флаги компилятора. Во время компоновки они не нужны.

Comment: Вам надо разобраться с этапами сборки (компиляция, компоновка) и понять какие флаги относятся к какому этапу.

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c main.c -o main.o` - компиляция. `gcc -o main main.o  -lcs50` - компоновка.

Comment: Поищите `CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, `LDLIBS`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо, поищу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен после настройки Makefile:

```
SRCS = main.c sigma-1.c swap.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LDLIBS = -lcs50 -lm
TARGET = main
CC = gcc

all: $(TARGET)

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
        rm -rf ./*.o

fclean:
        rm -rf $(TARGET) *.o

re: fclean all
```

Спасибо @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Следующий шаг - переход на [CMake](https://cmake.org/). `make` хорош чтобы понимать что под капотом, но поддержание зависимостей для быстрого перестроения проекта хотя бы среднего размера - головная боль в `make`.